# Construction of orthogonal basis in a 4d space

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

If we have a space $R^4$ and 3 given vectors, how can we construct a fourth vector which is normal to each one of the three given vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your vectors are $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Find the null space of the matrix whose rows are $x_1,x_2,x_3$ respectively. Any vector in the null space will be orthogonal to $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{x}=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}),\vec{y}=(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3},y_{4})$, and $\vec{z}=(z_{1},z_{2},z_{3},z_{4})$ be the three vectors. Then a generalization of the vector cross product in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is $$\operatorname{Det}\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\vec{e}_{1} & \vec{e}_{2} & \vec{e}_{3} & \vec{e}_{4}\\
x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} & x_{4}\\
y_{1} & y_{2} & y_{3} & y_{4}\\
z_{1} & z_{2} & z_{3} & z_{4}
\end{array}\right),$$ where $\{\vec{e}_{1},\vec{e}_{2}, \vec{e}_{3}, \vec{e}_{4}\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. This produces a fourth vector which is orthogonal to the original three vectors. In general, given $(n-1)$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, you can create a new vector orthogonal to the original vectors in the same manner using $\{\vec{e}_{1},\vec{e}_{2},\ldots,\vec{e}_{n}\}$ as the standard basis and computing the determinant of the resulting $n\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*} \operatorname{Det}
\begin{bmatrix}i&j&k&l\\a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4\\b_1&b_2&b_3&b_4\\c_1&c_2&c_3&c_4\end{bmatrix}  
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? maybe it's a hint, but it doesn't look like an answer…